# How to display put a button below inline block element?

Tags: javascript, css

I am trying to display a button just below a inline block element?

[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2tvHz.png) I want to put the button just below the title?

this is my code:

```
function(data) {
                var output;
                $.each(data.items, function(i,item) {
                    console.log(item);
                    videTitle = item.snippet.title;
                    videoId = item.snippet.resourceId.videoId;
                    output = '<li style="margin-bottom: 5%;"><img  style="display:inline; margin-right: 2%;" src="http://img.youtube.com/vi/'+videoId+'/hqdefault.jpg" width="150" class="img img-responsive" /><span style="font-size:16px;">'+videTitle+'</span><div class="buttons" style="position:absolute; margin: 1%;"><a class="bn btn-success" style="padding:3px;" href="https://www.youtube.com/watch?v='+videoId+'\">'+"Watch on Youtube"+'</a><a class="bn btn-primary" style="padding:4px; margin-left: 10px;" href="https://www.youtube.com/watch?v='+videoId+'\">'+"Convert to MP3"+'</a></div></li>';
                    $('#results').append(output);
                })
            }
```

I dont know why but i cannot do top right buttom left positioning on the button?

Comment: Hi, Can u please create a fiddle for the question for better understanding.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First let me start by saying that it is best to have your styles in a stylesheet not inline. anyways to use the "top right bottom left" you should have `position: relative` , absolute, or fixed. 
In your case I would advice using `position: relative` for the `li` and then you could use `position: absolute` relatively to the container